# JSONP Unexpected Syntax Error (API doesn't support JSONP)

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

My function:

```
function getMarketData_() {
      $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/',
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('ran');
      }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log('Error');
      });
    }
```

The Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The location of the error in the returned JSON:

[image]

Comment: Can we see the full json? Is `data` supposed to be an array by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, you can see it here: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/

Comment: it's almost as if json and jsonp are two different things.

Comment: @KevinB JSONP is an acronym for JSON Padded. See [Wikipedia - JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: sarcasm on the interwebs is fun

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't support JSONP.

To test click: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?callback=test

An API that supports JSONP would send back something like:

```
test({
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Bitcoin", 
            "symbol": "BTC", 
            "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
            "rank": 1, 
            "circulating_supply": 17095362.0, 
            "total_supply": 17095362.0, 
            "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 6530.3, 
                    "volume_24h": 4015800000.0, 
                    "market_cap": 111637842469.0, 
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.66, 
                    "percent_change_24h": -2.31, 
                    "percent_change_7d": -14.6
                }
            }, 
            "last_updated": 1529097276
        }
    }
})
```

For more information, see [Wikipedia - JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

See also [Angular 1.6.3 is not allowing a JSONP request that was allowed in 1.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706549/angular-1-6-3-is-not-allowing-a-jsonp-request-that-was-allowed-in-1-5-8/42710979#42710979)

---

The API supports CORS.

To test use:

https://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.coinmarketcap.com%2Fv2%2Fticker%2F&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote

---

This question typically arises when a user attempts to use `$http.get` and gets:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.[website].com/ No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4300' is therefore not allowed access.

Then someone suggests `$http.jsonp` as the workaround. This only works if the API supports JSONP.

For more information, see

- [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.[website].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)
- [Why does my JavaScript get a “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource” error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)
- [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs)
- [How to use Cors anywhere to reverse proxy and add CORS headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670703/how-to-use-cors-anywhere-to-reverse-proxy-and-add-cors-headers/32167044#32167044)

Comment: The API has a method to structure the data as an array, do you think this could be a workaround?

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?start=101&limit=10&sort=id&structure=array

Comment: The array structure is nice but it still is not JSONP because the required padding is not added. If the API doesn't support JSONP there is no workaround that will make `$http.jsonp` work. Use `$http.get` from an `https` origin or use a CORS proxy.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured.  Thanks for the insight.  I've been also trying to use $http.get but with that method I just get the CORS error:  "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".  Note that I'm running this from localhost.  When I run the exact same code from a site like Codepen, it works fine.

Comment: Codepen works because their origin is `https`. Your localhost doesn't work because the origin is `http`. Modern browsers block `http` to `https` cross origin requests.